# Как получить последнее сообщение в teleapi?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram

столкнулся с проблемой, написал простейший обработчик события `if message.text == 'Добавить'` и не могу сохранить последнее сообщение пользователя, все время сохраняет слово 'Добавить', я пробовал делать `bot.register_next_step_handler().`, но не вышло, мне нужно брать сообщение пользователя, которое идет после 'Добавить'. Надеюсь, что объяснил понятно, ибо сломал всю голову

```
import telebot
import config
import time
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN)

#обновляем список админов
users = open('main_users.txt', 'r')
admins = []
for user in users:
    admins.append(user.replace('\n', ''))


#комманды 
@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def start(message):
    global auth_btn
    auth = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    auth_btn = types.KeyboardButton('Войти')
    auth.add(auth_btn)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Приветствую, {0.first_name}!\nДля продолжения пройдите, пожалуйста, проверку'.format(message.from_user), 
    parse_mode='html', reply_markup=auth)



@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def main(message):
    user = message.from_user.username

    main = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    main_admin = types.KeyboardButton('Админы')
    main_temp = types.KeyboardButton('Шаблоны')
    main_ways = types.KeyboardButton('Маршруты')
    main.add(main_admin, main_temp, main_ways)

    edit_admin = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    back = types.KeyboardButton('Назад')
    delete = types.KeyboardButton('Удалить')
    add = types.KeyboardButton('Добавить')
    edit_admin.add(back, delete,add)

    if message.text == 'Войти':
        if user in admins:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Добро пожаловать, {0.first_name}'.format(message.from_user), parse_mode='html', reply_markup=main)
        else:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Извините, вас нет в списке пользователей, обратитесь к администратору')
    admin = ''
    cnt = 0
    for a in admins:
        cnt+=1
        admin += str(cnt)+ ': ' + a + '\n'
    if message.text == 'Админы':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, admin, reply_markup=edit_admin)
    if message.text == 'Добавить':
        add = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите id пользователя и <strong>отправьте</strong> сообщение', parse_mode='html')
        # print(message.text)
        # with open('main_users.txt', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        #     f.write('\n'+ message.text)
        #     f.close()
    
    if message.text == 'Удалить':
        pass
    if message.text == 'Назад':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Слушаю', parse_mode='html', reply_markup=main)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.infinity_polling()
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема довольно примитивная, как оказалось, вчера нашел решение. Нужно было использовать `bot.register_next_step_handler()`, вернее, правильное его использование. For ex.

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def welcome(message):
    mesg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Please send me message')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(mesg,test)


def test(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,message.text)
```